# Elementary Number Theory: Defining this multiplicative funcion, $G(n)$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given that $G(n)$ is a multiplicative function such that $G(n)=\sum_{d|n}\mu (d) \sigma(d)$, where $\mu(n) = 1$ if $n$ is square free with an even number of factors, $-1$ if $n$ is square free with an odd number of factors, and $0$ if $n$ has any square prime.  $\sigma(n)$ is the $\sigma$ we all know and love.

I need to find a formula for $G(p^k)$, but have no clue how to this - the $\mu$ function is quite foreign to me.

With this formula, I need to calculate $G(350)$.

Thanks!

Comment: familiar with mobius inversion formula ?

Comment: Not at all. I think my teacher is some kind of masochist. I got that $G(p^k)=2+p$... Is that somewhat close?  The first $\sigma$ gives us $\sigma(1)=1$, the second $\sigma(p)=1+p$. $\mu(1)=1$, and $\mu(p)=1$ and $\mu(p^{2,3,4,5,\dots})=0$, so $1 + (1+p)$ was my answer...

Comment: you're very close but shouldn't you be getting $1\color{red}{-}(1+p)$ ?

Comment: Yep! Hehe, thanks. :)

Comment: fix that and you're done! in general we have below for $n=p_1^{k_1}p_2^{k_2}\ldots p_r^{k_r}$ : $$\sum\limits_{d|n}\mu(d)\sigma(d) = (-1)^rp_1p_2\ldots p_r$$